# Understanding the injectivity of an isomorphism regarding the Galois group of a cyclic extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, proof-explanation, galois-theory

Here is the set-up from Milne's notes on *[Fields and Galois Theory](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf)* (page 71):

[image]

The line which I underlined is the one I have trouble to understand - could someone elaborate that part?
Everything before this line is clear to me.

In order to show why $\sigma$ is injective, it is probably smart to show that its kernel is trivial. However, I am not so sure what this has to do with $E$ being generated over $F$ by $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\sigma$ is an element of the kernel. Then $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$
and so $\sigma$ acts trivially on $E$ *because $\alpha$ generates $E$ over $F$*.
So $\sigma$ is the identity of $G$, and so the (unnamed) homomorphism is injective.